# Upload files with progress bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a small practical system to upload files to the server, I am using **Jquery, Jquery Ajax, PHP, Bootstrap 3, Fontawesome** y **Formvalidation.io**.

And I need collaboration to complete and add some features; so far I have managed to make the progress bar, and see the remaining amount of MB in real time;

**I want to do the following:**

1. Calculate in real time the amount of time remaining to upload the files or.
2. Where I can find information about events that are obtained from **addEventListener('progress', function(e){});** for example **e.loaded, e.total** etc...
3. Functionality that have **e.total** and  **e.loaded** events, and other events which may recommend them useful..
4. It is possible to obtain speed broadband user and based on that, establish an estimate for uploading files time default always put ten twenty seconds; for example, if a user is uploading a file but 2MB broadband speed is 56KB, it would take a long time to upload all files, and do not want to set default much for loading files.
5. You can speed up the response time of the server, after rising a file, because this doing several tests, and there are times that the server takes to give the answer, after the rise was completed, I tried other plugins, by example **Dropzone**, **Jquery file upload** y **Mini upload form**, and the response times are immediate, they seem to be much more efficient, if this be so, it is advisable to use a system to upload files to custom server as I am doing, or is it better to use some of these plugins I have named.

**Nota:** I copy the entire code in the HTML this all-inclusive code AJAX, linkable, no need to download libraries, only the path and file PHP, should create a folder and a PHP file with the code and change the path in the AJAX.

**AJAX code:**

**Note:** This code is already included in the HTML.

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Show modal
        $("#modal_system").modal('show');       
    },
    url: 'ajax/1.4_ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 120000,
    xhr: function() {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

        console.log('XHR: ', myXhr);

        if (myXhr.upload) {                     
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){

                    var loaded = e.loaded;
                    var total = e.total;
                    var percentComplete = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                    // Quantity of bytes per second
                    var leftover_bytes =   total - loaded;
                    var leftover_bytes =   leftover_bytes / 1048576;
                    $('.modal-body #dataResponse').html( leftover_bytes.toFixed(2) + ' MB' );

                    // Progress bar function
                    $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                    $('.progress .progress-bar').html( percentComplete + '%');

            }, false);
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function(e){
                // After upload cant reset progrees bar
                //$('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
                //$('.progress .progress-bar').html( '');
            }, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    }

})
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Upload files Jquery Ajax - XHR2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/formvalidation/formvalidation.io/master/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Main</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/ Header -->


    <!-- Upload file -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h1>Upload files</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" multiple>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                            <p id="response"></p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ Upload file -->


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/formvalidation/formvalidation.io/master/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/formvalidation/formvalidation.io/master/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {

        $('#form').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            excluded: ':disabled',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
               image: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Image field required.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form    = $(e.target),
                fv       = $form.data('formValidation');
                formData = new FormData(),
                params   = $form.serializeArray(),
                image    = $form.find('[name="image"]')[0].files;

            $.each(image, function(i, file) {
                // Prefix the name of uploaded files with "docs-"
                // Of course, you can change it to any string
                formData.append('image[]', file);
            });

            $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            // Info add send post
            formData.append('id', Math.random());

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // Show modal
                    $("#modal_system").modal('show');       
                },
                url: 'ajax/1.4_ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 120000,
                xhr: function() {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                    console.log('XHR: ', myXhr);

                    if (myXhr.upload) {                     
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){

                                var loaded = e.loaded;
                                var total = e.total;
                                var percentComplete = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                                // Quantity of bytes per second
                                var leftover_bytes =   total - loaded;
                                var leftover_bytes =   leftover_bytes / 1048576;
                                $('.modal-body #dataResponse').html( leftover_bytes.toFixed(2) + ' MB' );

                                // Progress bar function
                                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                                $('.progress .progress-bar').html( percentComplete + '%');

                        }, false);
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function(e){
                            // After upload cant reset progrees bar
                            //$('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
                            //$('.progress .progress-bar').html( '');
                        }, false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                }

            }).done( function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // Before success

              $('p#response').html( data.message );

            }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Before error

              switch(jqXHR.status) {
                case 0:
                  $('p#response').html( 'Timeout exceeded.' );
                break;

                case 403:
                  $('p#response').html( 'The session has expired.' );
                break;

                case 404:
                  $('p#response').html( 'The requested page does not exist.' );
                break;

                default:
                  if(jqXHR.status != 200) {
                    $('p#response').html( 'Error please try again has occurred.' );
                  }
                break;
              }

              console.log(jqXHR);
              //console.log('Estatus readyState:' + jqXHR.readyState);
              //console.log('Estatus status:' + jqXHR.status);
              //console.log('Estatus statusText:' + jqXHR.statusText);
              //console.log('Estatus responseText:' + jqXHR.responseText);
              //console.log('Estatus setRequestHeader:' + jqXHR.setRequestHeader);

            });
        });

    });
    </script>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_system" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Example</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
        <div><strong>Quantity left: </strong> <span id="dataResponse"></span></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php 

    /**
     * Function to organize uploaded files
     */     
    function organizeArray( $arr ){
        foreach( $arr as $key => $all ){
            foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
                $new[$i][$key] = $val;    
            }    
        }
        return $new;
    }

    // Array organized
    $image = organizeArray( $_FILES['image'] );

    // Configurations
    $document_root  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $directory      = "../files/";

    // Browse array
    foreach ($image as $key => $value) {
        move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $directory . '1.2 -' . date('h-i-s') . $value['name']);
    }

    $data = array(
        'response' => true,
        'message' => 'Completed'
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

¡Much appreciate your support!!

*Thank you very much*

Comment: Unless you are doing this for your own learning benefit there are numerous available scripts for this already that have been cross browser tested and have configurable feature sets and numerous event hooks

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, if I am making this practical custom system, to implement plugins predesigned can sometimes be tedious, and I think if we do custom should be more practical and easy to implement but do not really know if it is so efficient.

Comment: But downside is time involved as well as cross browser testing. Existing solutions would be simple to configure for what you are doing plus they already provide features beyond what you have

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm trying to configure the plugins that I have appointed and work, but the integration with a form and other kingpins texts, and have a more specific control is more complex, for example: If a user is filling out a fomrulario , and has already uploaded files, but canceled submit the form, the files would remain on the server, and a solution is that the files be uploaded to the server once the form is submitted, but have not managed to do that.